# GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC.NET website that I developed on my home PC that works perfectly.  I use git and Visual Studio Online as source control.  When I get to work and pull it down, it compiles just fine, but when I try to run the site, it always hangs on:

Global.asax.cs Application_Start()

`AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`

and/or

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

It hangs on the first, but if I comment it out, it hangs on the second.  If I comment both out, the site displays, but then the WebAPI routing breaks.

However, if I create a new site, it all works just fine.  I thought maybe it had something to do with my NuGet packages, so I removed/readded anything related to MVC and WebAPI, but no luck.

I'm new to the whole MVC.NET world, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit #1: I forgot to mention that it works find on both my home desktop and my home laptop.  All transfers going through Visual Studio Online.  It's only when I pull it down to my work PC, it doesn't work.

Comment: it seems you are doing something wrong with pull and push of code on version control, can you make sure if you are getting exactly same copy which you are uploading

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You could be right, but I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, because I can push and pull between my home desktop and home laptop without any problems.

Comment: No error message, just freezes?

Comment: It doesn't really "freeze".  The browser opens up and it looks like it's loading, but the page just loads and loads with no end.  I've let it set for over 30 minutes before!  But the loading wheel is still rotating, but nothing actually loads.  And if I set a break point, it will break successfully on the lines mentioned above, but if I simply try to step over either of those lines, that's where it hangs.

Comment: @JasonThuli Did you ever find a resolution to this? This exact problem started happening to me and my team out of nowhere. Our IT department installed Office 2013 over the weekend, but that's the only thing that's changed as far as I know. Other than that it just broke out of nowhere. The solution works when it's deployed to a server.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project and do the initial commit, check in the team explorer window if there are any files listed in the "Untracked Files" section at the bottom.

I faced a similar problem some time ago and it was related with missing files.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already check for any untracked files each time I commit.